# Imagem do modelo não faz upload

Tags: django, django-2.0

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma app que precisa que o usuário faça upload de sua imagem de perfil, porém o mecanismo 'upload_to' do campo ft de CustomUser,aparentemente não está funcionando. A imagem simplesmente não vai para a pasta destinada, nem cria a pasta com o nome desejado, no caso 'fotos', que como deveria acontecer. Já tentei recriá-lo e nada.

models.py

```
#TODO: MODEL ADMIN E PAI DOS DEMAIS MODELS DE LOGIN
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(_('E-mail '), max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(_('Nome de usuário '), max_length=15, unique=True)
    choice = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ft = models.ImageField(upload_to='fotos', null=True, blank=True, default='../media/site/user.png')
    date_joined = models.CharField(_('Data de início '), max_length=20, default=timezone.now())
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username', 'choice']
    objects = UserManager()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Usuário')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Usuários')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

forms.py

```
 class CustomCompanyCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
        class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
            model = CustomCompany
            fields = ('name', 'departamento', 'cnpj', 'ft', 'telefone','cep', 'endereco', 'cidade', 'uf', 'username', 'email'
                  )
```

pag.html

```
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% for hidden_field in form.hidden_fields %}
  {{ hidden_field }}
{% endfor %}

{% if form.non_field_errors %}
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
      {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endif %}

{% for field in form.visible_fields %}
  <div class="form-group">
    <hr>
    {{ field.label_tag }}

    {% if form.is_bound %}
      {% if field.errors %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-invalid placeholder=form.text.label" %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <div class="invalid-feedback">
            {{ error }}
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% else %}
        {% render_field field class="form-control is-valid placeholder=form.text.label" %}
      {% endif %}
    {% else %}
      {% render_field field class="form-control" placeholder=form.text.label %}
    {% endif %}

    {% if field.help_text %}
      <small class="form-text text-muted">{{ field.help_text|safe }}</small>
    {% endif %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Eu coloquei este código para alterar a foto com o cadastro já feito e o mecanismo para salvar a foto no cadastro parou.

views.py para alterar foto:

```
def fotoPerfil_change(request, id):
        customuser = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=id)
        form = ChangePhoto(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=customuser)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            suc = "Foto de perfil atualizada com sucesso!"
            return render(request,'perfil/fotoperfil.html', {'form':form, 'suc': suc})
        return render(request, 'perfil/fotoperfil.html', {'form': form})
```

views.py do cadastro:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None, initial={
            'choice': True})
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.choice = 0
            user.set_password(user.password)
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'register-sucess.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register-f.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: seria bom você também inserir o código da sua view

Comment: Eu coloquei este código para alterar a foto com o cadastro já feito e o mecanismo para salvar a foto no cadastro parou.`def fotoPerfil_change(request, id):
        customuser = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, pk=id)
        form = ChangePhoto(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=customuser)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            suc = "Foto de perfil atualizada com sucesso!"
            return render(request,'perfil/fotoperfil.html', {'form':form, 'suc': suc})
        return render(request, 'perfil/fotoperfil.html', {'form': form})`

Comment: O código anterior refere-se à ao mecanismo de troca de imagem, agora segue o views.py `def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomUserCreationForm(request.POST or None, initial={
            'choice': True})
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.choice = 0
            user.set_password(user.password)
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'register-sucess.html', {'user': user})
    else:
        form = CustomUserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'register-f.html', {'form': form})`

Comment: seria melhor você colocar o código na pergunta, da mesma maneira como você fez com o código do forms, models e template. Aqui nos comentário fica bem difícil de ler o código

Comment: Pronto, realmente agora está mais claro.